Aussprache von "Triumph"
Das Wort "Triumph" kommt (lt. Kluge/Seebold, Etymologisches Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache) von lateinisch "triumphus", was soviel wie "feierlicher Einzug" oder "Siegeszug" bedeutet.
Nach dieser Quelle ist das deutsche Wort verwandt mit den von derselben Herkunft abgeleiteten neu-niederländischen "triomf", dem neu-norwegischen "triumf" und ähnlichen, das "ph" scheint also wohl eine Umschreibung des griechischen "Phi" (Φ, φ oder ϕ) zu sein, das zwar ursprünglich als behauchter bilabialer Plosiv ("ph" woher auch die Umschreibung "ph" kommt), allerdings bereits im Koine (ab etwa dem 4. Jahrhundert v.u.Z) als bilabialer Frikativ ("f") gesprochen wurde.
Dies alles würde also dafür sprechen, das Wort, wie es auch das Niederländische oder Norwegische tun, als triumf auszusprechen. Hingegen hört man aber überwiegend triumpf, also mit einem hörbaren "p" und auch das davon abgeleitete Wort "Trumpf" (eine Karte im Kartenspiel, die alles sticht) schreibt diese Aussprache fort. Demgegenüber wird bei Weiterbildungen wie "triumphal" üblicherweise auf das "p" beim Sprechen verzichtet, also triumfal und nicht triumpfal.
Mich würden Einschätzungen interessieren, woher diese offensichtliche Diskrepanz bei der Aussprache kommt.

Ich vermute, dass es eine phonotaktische Beschränkung (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Phonotactics) des Deutschen ist, dass der Laut mf am Wortende nicht existiert. Ich habe gerade kein rückläufiges Wörterbuch zur Hand, um diese Hypothese zu überprüfen, daher hier nur als Arbeitshypothese im Kommentar.

Das wäre dann so ähnlich wie bei "Senf", der in manchen Gegenden als "Senft" oder auch ähnlich wie "Sempft" ausgesprochen wird.

Ja, genau. In Sachsen, wo ich aufgewachsen bin, ist es eher Sempf. Auch die Endung nf ist ja eine Ausnahme (mein Großvater kannte einen Spruch mit allen fünf deutschen Wörtern, die auf nf enden, aber er fällt mir nicht mehr ein).

@JonathanHerrera: fünf?? Ich kenne nur "Hanf", "Senf", "Genf" und "fünf". Was ist das fünfte?

Sernf: https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-fuenf-woerter-auf-nf-a-315962.html @bakunin

Sernf ist ein 19 km langer Fluss in der Schweiz.

Es ist eine generelle Regel in vielen Dialekten des Deutschen zwischen n/l und s/sch ein t einzufügen: So wird als als alz, Gans als Ganz oder Wunsch als Wuntsch ausgesprochen. Folgt ein Vokal, ist die Aussprache mit t seltener, aber vor allem unauffälliger, denn ein stimmhaftes ds wie in einer Aussprache von Gänse als Gändse ist kein eigenes Phonem. Auffällig ist, dass alle diese Laute in der Mitte des Mundes (alveolar) gebildet werden und das Phänomen folglich bei -ms nicht auftritt.
Die phonotaktische Regel lautet also: Folgt am Ende einer Silbe ein Frikativ auf einen Nasal / auf L von der gleichen Artikulationsort, so kann der Frikativ zum Affrikat werden.
Es ist davon auszugehen, dass diese Regel auch anwendbar ist, wenn Frikativ und Nasal von den Lippen (labial) gebildet werden, also zwischen m und f. Das betritt außer Triumph auch Nymphe, und siehe da, Nymphe hat für viele Sprecher auch ein p.
Auch ganz pragmatisch: Bei einem Nasal wird ein Verschluss gebildet, der für den Frikativ leicht geöffnet werden muss, ein Frikativ, der mit einem Verschluss beginnt, ist aber ein Affrikat, es ist also schwierig, einen konsistenten Unterschied zwischen mf und mpf zu produzieren.
Disclaimer: Für mich ist der Unterschied zwischen "pf" und "f" nicht phonemisch, ich habe große Schwierigkeiten, einen Unterschied zu hören.

"Sümpfe" und "Symphonien" sind ein weiteres Paar, wo man den Klang gut vergleichen kann (und vermutlich keinen erkennen wird).

Es heißt Synfonie, @O.R.Mapper, wie in sündhaft schön; fünf, aber gelegentlich wohl doch auch fümpf, wie schon umbrisch oskisch pumpe, lateinisch quinque, quint-.

@vectory: Nein, es heißt Symphonie oder alternativ Sinfonie.

naja sag ich ja, mit ie wie in hab dih lüb

Auf der Duden-Website https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Triumph kann man sich die (offizielle?) Aussprache anhören. Für mich hört sich das wie Triumf an, aber es ist tatsächlich schwer von Triumpf zu unterscheiden. Das Wort "Triumphmarsch" hat übrigens laut Duden die Lautschrift triˈʊmfmarʃ.
Vielleicht verleitet die Ähnlichkeit mit dem Wort "Trumpf" viele Sprecher dazu, ein "p" einzubauen, und viele Hörer dazu, ein "p" zu erahnen, obwohl es gar nicht gesprochen wurde? Ich vermute also eine Art "akustische Täuschung".
Eine Google-Suche nach Werbevideos zeigt ein ähnliches Ergebnis: Die Aussprache wabert zwischen "Triumpf" und "Triumf".
Zum Selbsttest sollte man mehrfach das nicht existierend Wort "Sumf" aussprechen. Auch das ist kaum von "Sumpf" zu unterscheiden.
